# grep for a pattern in each line

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I have a large file with the below URLs and want to create different directories for each URL in a bash script giving the below file named URLs as input to the bash script.

```
www.example.com/B000742278U3/B000742278U3.m3u8?p=33&e=1481028335&h=5380934bbca73e3e6de52299b92368b1
www.example.com/B000742279U3/B000742279U3.m3u8?p=33&e=1481028335&h=5380934bbca73e3e6de52299b92368b1
www.example.com/B000742280U3/B000742280U3.m3u8?p=33&e=1481028335&h=5380934bbca73e3e6de52299b92368b1
```

Expected output:

```
B000742278U3
B000742279U3
B000742280U3
```

I tried the command below, but couldn't achieve what I wanted:

```
echo $1
mkdir $(echo $1 | sed 's/.*B\(.*\)3/\1/')
cd $(echo $1 | sed 's/.*B\(.*\)3/\1/')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an `awk` version :

`awk -F/ '{print $2}' | xargs mkdir`

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the slash as a field delimiter in `cut`:

```
$ cut -d '/' -f 2 infile
B000742278U3
B000742279U3
B000742280U3
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try this

```
 cut -d '/' -f2 | xargs mkdir
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[./]' '{print $5}' file

B000742278U3
B000742279U3
B000742280U3
```